# Finding all combinations of record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's imagine if that I have 5 User records in the db, one of those 5 records is a user with age attribute 30.

And that I want to find or create two users with `age` attribute 28 and 30.

If I do this :

```
User.where(age: [28, 30])
```

This will give me a single user which has age 30, but it won't give me back the user with age 28 (doesn't exist).

Or if I do this

```
User.where(age: 28).where(age: 30)
```

There is no record with both ages present. Let's imagine age is just an arbitrary attribute, and the age value is an arbitrary value which can be anything.

How would I get all the records based on certain attributes/values combination and if they don't exist yet, create them?

Comment: The title doesn't describe the question.  You're not asking how to find combinations of a record, you're asking how to `find_or_create` multiple records on multiple conditions at the same time.

Comment: I am assuming your example is hypothetical, because ages and users just does not make any sense to me (making random users of a certain age?).  In short: this is not possible, there is no short-cut, no `find_or_create_by` in one go. There is no telling, from such a where-clause, which options where not met and then create those? Could you explain what you are trying to achieve more specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use a [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) on the [where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) conditions:

```
User.where(age: (28..30))
```

This will work for finding. To create a new user with the age of missing values I believe you will need to code it by hand.

Comment: if I have a user with age 29, will this pick it up?

Comment: Just tested it. It will.

Comment: that's not what I wanted. Thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 2):

If you want a range, you can just put a raw SQL statement in the where clause, like this:

```
User.where("age >= 28 AND age <= 30")
```

If you want a specific set of ages, you can use a list in the where clause:

```
unless User.where("age IN (28,30)").length > 0
    # Code to create user with the age you want
end
```

Finally, there's also the `first_or_initialize` and `first_or_create` methods, which can be joined to where clauses. If no record is found from the `where` search, one is initialized/created.

```
User.where("age IN (28,30)").first_or_initialize
```

Rails 4 has a similar `find_or_create_by` method.

Comment: will this create a both records in condition? one being already in the db and another one which doesn't exist?

Comment: I do not think the last method is primed to create everything missing in your range. If you want to do that, you'll need to loop over every value missing from the range you want and create them.